# Detect a user change of a <select> list created with Jquery ".html()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to detect when the value of a select list is changed, when this select list have been added with the `.html(htmlString)` or `.append(content[,content])` jQuery function?

HTML CODE:

```
<ul class="htmlClass">
   <!-- Populated via JS -->
</ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
var MyDropDownMenu= "";
MyDropDownMenu += '<select class="field">';
MyDropDownMenu += '<option value="1">Option 1</option>';
MyDropDownMenu += '<option value="2">Option 2</option>';
MyDropDownMenu += '</select>';
$('ul.htmlClass').html(MyDropDownMenu);

$(".field").change( function() {   //Doesn't work!!!
      alert("test1");
});

$(".htmlClass").change( function() {  //work        
      alert("test2");
});
```

Comment: you shouldn't be adding a `select` to `ul`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use event delegation

```
$('ul.htmlClass').on('change',".field", function() { 
      alert("test1");
});
```

- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 4):

Use delegated event handlers

```
$('ul.htmlClass').on('change','.field', function() {
  alert("test1"); 
});
```

See [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more information.

Another problem in your code is that you're adding your `select` directly to the `ul` element. This is not correct.

I see two options

1) wrap `select` with a `li` tag

```
var MyDropDownMenu= "<li>";
myDropDownMenu += '<select class="field">';
MyDropDownMenu += '<option value="1">Option 1</option>';
MyDropDownMenu += '<option value="2">Option 2</option>';
MyDropDownMenu += '</select>';
MyDropDownMenu += '</li>';
```

2) Convert your `ul` to a `div` if you don't require a list

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes I did wrap select with a <li> but thank you for this  precise reply!